# removing just "?m=1" from url using rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, blogger

just few day before i had migrated my blogger blog to wordpress. Now i find crawn error with many url, at the end of many url  the name and value is there  (?m=1) which shown as a 404 error now i want to redirect all the url additing .htaccess file
example:

http://www.tipsviablogging.com/blogger-tricks/facebook-disqus-tab-in-blogger.html?m=1

musy redirect to

http://www.tipsviablogging.com/blogger-tricks/facebook-disqus-tab-in-blogger.html

any one is having expertise in url rewrite kindly help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't got a test system handy, but something like this in your `.htaccess` should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

If memory serves, you need the `?` at the end of the target in the `RewriteRule` to stop the original query string being appended.

The code assumes you haven't got any other parameters (eg it won't work if you have `?m=1&foo=bar`).

Comment: wow its what i actually needed, thanks a lot Hobo for your support and time for me.. i really thanks full to you i had successfully applied above code and got the solution now every link is redirected what i needed, ^-^

Comment: Great news; if my answer did what you needed, can you mark it as accepted (click the tick/check mark beside my answer) and/or vote it up?  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a solution on NginX:

Use below code in "location /" Of VirtualHost config

```
if ($query_string ~ "^m=1$"){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1? redirect;
}
```