# Blogger To Wordpress Migration Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, blogger

I'm facing an issue after migrating my blog from Blogger to Wordpress.

My all old links are properly redirecting to WP but there are few `404` errors in my Google Webmaster Tools account.
For example: www.bloggertipstricks.com/2013/03/seo-tips.html?m=1

There is an extra parameter added after the URL (?m=1). Anybody please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check out [my answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940522/removing-just-m-1-from-url-using-rewrite-rule/18943880#18943880). Seems the asker had the same problem as you (I'd mark your question as a duplicate, but since he hasn't accepted me answer I can't).

Comment: Actually I'm facing problem in where to put that code?

Comment: It goes in your `.htaccess` file.  I'm assuming you're running Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Here I got solution for this. As you know that Blogger also ends with `?m=0` with `?m=1` so you have to remove both from URLs. So try the below codes by adding them in the top of `.htaccess` file...

You you can use the following code in any version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=0$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$0? [R=301,L]
```

In Apache 2.4 and above you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=[01]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

In lower version of Apache then 2.4 you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=[01]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```